# Why the first client sees to have source ip of 0.0.0.0?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, udp

I have a `client.c` `server.c` on linux. on both I init a socket:

```
sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)
```

in the server I add:

```
listen_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
listen_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
listen_adrr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
```

the `server.c` calls (blocking way) to `recvform`:

```
if (recvfrom(sockfd, buf_get, BUFLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&talker_addr, &slen) == -1)
            err("recvfrom()");
```

And the `client.c` sends packets with:

```
if (sendto(sockfd, buf_sent, BUFLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, slen) == -1)
        err("sendto()");
```

1. The problem is that on the first calling to `sendto` from
   `client.c`, the servers sees the client's ip as `0.0.0.0`, after
   that on the second, third,... calls the `client.c` get an ip and
   have a legal ip such as `127.0.0.3:3212`.
2. another weird thing is that if I start a second new client it gets
   ip from the first time.

Comment: What is the initial value of `talker_addr`? And define 'the server sees'.

Comment: the server sees means the result of talker_addr from recvfrom

Comment: Not being able to see where you're checking talker_addr, it's not clear that you're not getting an error code from recvfrom.  If that's the case, obviously the talker_addr address isn't meaningful

Comment: Also, what are you setting slen to?

Comment: @EJP talker_addr shouldn't need any initial value.  it's an output parameter to recvfrom.  http://linux.die.net/man/3/recvfrom

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Make sure you are setting slen to the size of the talker_addr struct before you call recvfrom.  It will set the value (which may explain why it works in subsequent calls) in recvfrom but if there is a bad initial value, you may get garbage the first call.

```
slen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
```

Comment: This is likely the correct answer. As per the man page for recvfrom: *"The returned address is truncated if the buffer provided is too small; in this case, addrlen will return a value greater than was supplied to the call."*  So his address length member gets properly initialized AFTER he makes the first recvfrom call.